# How to find data usage of newly installed application in Android

Tags: android

How to find data usage of newly installed application?

**getUidTxBytes(int uid) and getUidRxBytes(int uid)** are used to get the data usage, but in case if a new app is installed and using the data, how can I identify that the new app is installed? And also how come I know the newly installed app getting data usage?
I am pretty new to this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for Broadcast Intents from the system like `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED` to be notified when new applications are installed or updgraded.  The UID of the package is always passed with these Intents as an extra.

[SDK Docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) for more information.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, i got understand how to do this.